# Calculate daily average duration for two step process

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, aggregation

I have a dataframe that looks like the below.

```
data = {'user': [3249, 2160, 2160, 3249, 5120, 3900, 3900, 3900, 5200, 5200], 'action': ['step 1', 'step 1', 'step 2', 'step 2', 'step 1', 'step 1', 'step 1', 'step 2', 'step 1', 'step 2'], 'time': ['2021-10-25 19:45:43', '2021-10-25 19:48:46', '2021-10-25 19:50:21', '2021-10-25 19:57:34', '2021-10-25 20:30:56', '2021-10-25 20:35:40', '2021-10-25 20:50:59', '2021-10-25 21:15:08', '2021-10-25 18:23:41', '2021-10-26 18:49:38']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.sort_values('time', inplace=True)

df

user    action  time
8   5200    step 1  2021-10-25 18:23:41
0   3249    step 1  2021-10-25 19:45:43
1   2160    step 1  2021-10-25 19:48:46
2   2160    step 2  2021-10-25 19:50:21
3   3249    step 2  2021-10-25 19:57:34
4   5120    step 1  2021-10-25 20:30:56
5   3900    step 1  2021-10-25 20:35:40
6   3900    step 1  2021-10-25 20:50:59
7   3900    step 2  2021-10-25 21:15:08
9   5200    step 2  2021-10-26 18:49:38
```

I would like to be able to calculate the average time it takes for a user to go from step 1 to step 2, and then grouping by day so end up with something that looks like this:

| Date | Avg Duration |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-25 | 752 seconds |
| 2021-10-26 | 87957 seconds |

Following up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69714327/calculate-average-daily-duration-for-a-complete-two-step-process), I tried the following but it doesn't work when I introduce instances where a user doesn't complete both step 1 and 2 on the same day. I would like that if a user starts step 1 on 2021-10-25, and completes step 2 on 2021-10-26, the time duration is recorded for 2021-10-26.

```
out = df.pivot_table(index=['user', df['time'].dt.date], columns='action',
                     values='time', aggfunc='last').reset_index()

out['daily_avg'] = out.groupby(['user', 'time'], as_index=False) \
                      .apply(lambda x: x['step 2'] - x['step 1']).values

out.groupby('time')['daily_avg'].mean(numeric_only=False).reset_index()

    time    daily_avg
0   2021-10-25  -42701 days +05:00:36.258089984
1   2021-10-26  NaT
```

Comment: User `3900` has 2 `step 1`'s on `2021-10-25`. Which one do you take as reference to compute the time difference? Is there a case where an user has multiple `step 1` and multiple `step 2` in a day?

Comment: the later step 1 would be used as this would mean that the user restarted the process. it is possible for a user to have multiple step 1s and 2s in a day if they completes the process multiple times. A user cannot go to step 2 if they does not first go to step 1, but can restart at step 1 as much as they like

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a logic-intensive step to clean up the data before using pandas's easy methods. Like Hoang pointed out, user 3900 has 2 step-1s followed by 1 step-2. The interpretation of that has to be dealt with before you aggregate. If you assume a 1-to-1 relationship and the last step-1 is the valid one (assuming user-terminated the previous step-1 or it crashed, etc), you should remove those duplicates. The question further complicates if a user runs step-1 to step-2 many times successfully, but the last time step-2 did not start. Thus you cannot just choose the last time per user-step.

My preference is usually to assume the ugliest data exist, and do a 1-to-1 matching, thus dropping the discontinued step-1s, before using the pandas aggregate and pivot functions.